# SQL Management Studio: Can i change the tray icon?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I always have loads on windows open and i can very see the SQL Management Studio when it is minimised, the icon is too light a color

Is there a way of changing the icon?

Comment: If only the problems and dramas of the day were of this magnitude :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like [Resource Tuner](http://www.restuner.com/) to tweak the icon inside ssms.exe

Answer (score 0):

Well, not in Windows 7 you can "pin" it to fixed position on task-bar. (Right-click icon on task-bar, when SSMS is open - you will see a "pin"). So you will always know that it is located for example at the beginning of the task-bar.